# Service com FileSystemWatcher não fica escutando para sempre

Tags: c#, services

Estou fazendo um Serviço do windows em C#, que escuta uma pasta e toda vez que tem um arquivo de audio ele faz o upload.

O Problema é que ele funciona, porém depois de alguns minutos para de escutar a pasta, não causa problema o serviço continua startado, mas para de funcionar.
Se eu simplesmente dar um stop e um star ele processa de novo.

Para tentar debugar eu fiz que ele gravasse um log, txt que também gravasse no registro do windows (enchi de try/catch e coloquei para registrar) Mas não consigo, descobri.

Agora movi todo o projeto para uma ClassLibrary assim posso criar um programa console e tentar debugar, mas nda.

Meu código (apenas algumas partes):

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
          FileRepo.VerificaArquivosExistentes().ContinueWith(async result =>
           {
                var fw = new FileRepo(true);
                 await fw.FileWatch();
          });
    }
        public async Task FileWatch()
        {
            var pathAudio = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathGravacao"];
            var codec = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Codec"];

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                Path = pathAudio,
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName,
                Filter = codec
            };
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            watcher.Changed += Fsw_Changed;
//essa aqui é uma tentativa de força ele ficar na escuta para sempre
            await Task.Delay(Int32.MaxValue);
        }


   internal static void Fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var hashBlob = Guid.NewGuid();
            var fullPath = e.FullPath;
            UploadFileAsync(e.FullPath, hashBlob).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            DataRepo.GravaRegistroDapperAsync(fullPath, hashBlob).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            DeletarArquivo(fullPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log log = new Log();
            log.WriteEntry(ex);
            GravarTXT.Gravar("====> ERRO");
            GravarTXT.Gravar("          " + ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Como está o resto do serviço... você está dando um thread sleep e executando a task novamente?

Comment: não...eu apenas tentei com um await Task.Delay(Int32.MaxValue); para segurar a aplicação...porém acredito que a escuta do FileSystemWatcher executaria o delegate com qualquer modificação em qualquer momento...mas pelo visto a app para

Comment: Não seria melhor você invocar o evento após a criação do arquivo processar e remover da pasta de entrada?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo não entendi...

Comment: Não sei se precisa da resposta ainda, porém percebi olhando para seu código que você está monitorando só os arquivos alterados, não deveria monitorar os arquivos criados? Não dá erro mesmo, simplesmente seu watcher está ignorando os novos arquivos. Tente adicionar também: watcher.Created += Fsw_Changed;